# Drop down value is getting reset

Tags: jsp

Drop down value is getting reset to the last value in the list on page submit.

The below is my code snippet.

```
<select id="rqsttype" name="rqsttype" class="InputField" onchange="disableStartDt();">
    <option value="-1" selected> Select
    <option value="calculated"> Calculated
    <option value="ext"> Extension
    <option value="additonal"> Additonal
    <option value="tbd"> TBD
</select>
```

Comment: Then what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please define your Javascript `onChange` function that you have made for dropdown.

```
onchange="disableStartDt();"
```